# Sprites With Vastly Disparate Scales

Tags: xna, 2d, sprites, monogame

So, I'm developing a 2D game where I'm dealing with sprites with vastly different scales. I'm attempting to represent the scales accurately, where I have a 10-m wingspan fighter and a 1400-m carrier that launches it. The trouble I'm running into, is if I draw the fighter out to be 100px wide, then the carrier needs to be 14,000 px. I believe the XNA game engine I'm running supports only up to 8096x8096 sizes, so I'm a little unsure what to do. Thank for your help, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't represent the carrier with a single sprite. Represent it with a tilemap.

So instead of having one 14000px wide sprite for the carrier flight deck, have a 32x32px sprite for runway without markings and one with lines on it. Then draw these two tiles as often as you need to.

This might sound slower than drawing just one sprite, but has the advantage that you only need to draw those tiles which are actually on the screen.